# mysterious 404 error

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-404

When you load [this page](http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/), a 404 error appears in Firebug

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/undefined
```

My best guess is that some javascript var that should resolve to an image, .js, or .css file is undefined, but I'm not sure how to go about tracking down the code responsible.

Comment: `Accept image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5`
is a image which are not loaded successfully.

Comment: I can't see any missing images on the site, is there any way to get the name of the image that is failing to load?

Comment: Yes, but now, I can't find the solution. Investigating.

Comment: I think is the `infiniteCarousel` who are causing the problem.

Comment: -1: Remove components one by one until you find it. This is called _debugging_.

Comment: Yes, tested and is the `infiniteCarousel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have console open while the page loads you see the error on a stack:

```
 GET http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/undefined 404 (Not Found)
    f.extend.cleanjquery-1.7.1.min.js:4
    f.buildFragmentjquery-1.7.1.min.js:4
    f.fn.extend.domManipjquery-1.7.1.min.js:4
    f.fn.extend.appendjquery-1.7.1.min.js:3
    $.fn.extend.infiniteCarouselbundle-true_defer.js:562
    e.extend.eachjquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
    e.fn.e.eachjquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
    $.fn.extend.infiniteCarouselbundle-true_defer.js:428
    _optionshttp://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/:452
    f.Callbacks.njquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
    f.Callbacks.o.fireWithjquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
    e.extend.readyjquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
    c.addEventListener.Bjquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
```

Comment: so it's the infinitecarousel that's causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would start by using the non-minified version of jQuery. If you load the page in Chrome and open the Developer Tools you can see the /undefined resource was loaded by jQuery. If you use the non-minified version it should be easy to set a breakpoint in the jQuery file where the resource is being loaded to find the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with this code `bundle-trued_defer.js`

```
// No tabs left to sho
this.activeTab_ = undefined;
```

When all images are loaded, tha last to load will be a undefined page.

Change this

```
  if (tab.tab == this.activeTab_) {
    // Removing the current active tab
    if (this.tabs_[index]) {
      // Show the tab to the right
      this.activeTab_ = this.tabs_[index].tab;
    } else if (this.tabs_[index - 1]) {
      // Show a tab to the left
      this.activeTab_ = this.tabs_[index - 1].tab;
    } else {
      // No tabs left to sho
      this.activeTab_ = undefined;
    }

    this.setTabActive_(this.activeTab_);
  }
```

To

```
  if (tab.tab == this.activeTab_) {
    // Removing the current active tab
    if (this.tabs_[index]) {
      // Show the tab to the right
      this.activeTab_ = this.tabs_[index].tab;
    } else if (this.tabs_[index - 1]) {
      // Show a tab to the left
      this.activeTab_ = this.tabs_[index - 1].tab;
    } else {
      // No tabs left to sho
      this.activeTab_ = undefined;
    }

    if(this.activeTab_ !== undefined) {
        this.setTabActive_(this.activeTab_);
    }
  }
```

With this, and verify if work.

Comment: I tested your change, but it didn't fix the problem. The code you've posted above is part of Google maps. When I run the app locally, this code isn't even loaded by the home page, but I still see the error